# nginx with proxy_pass returning wrong proxy_set_header

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am doing reverse proxy:

```
server {
    listen 90 ssl;
    server_name 192.168.5.11;

    location /myshop/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.5.10:80/another_shop/;

        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        add_header Front-End-Https   on;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

When I visit https://192.168.5.11:90/myshop/, in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], I have 
/another_shop/ instead of the "virtual" nginx location /myshop/

Comment: You are describing the expected behaviour. If you want the server at `192.168.5.10:80` to receive the original request, then remove the `/another_shop/` part from the `proxy_pass` statement.

Comment: I don't want to "expose"/reverse proxy the other folders found on http://192.168.5.10:80/

Comment: You just saved my life by asking this question and posting your snipped. Thank you./

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines in nginx configuration

```
location /myshop/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #proxy_connect_timeout       86400;
    #proxy_send_timeout          86400;
    #proxy_read_timeout          86400;
    #send_timeout                86400;
    #client_max_body_size 50m;
    #client_body_buffer_size 16k;
}
```